# Retry to send an email when first fails - codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I have this code that send email notifications and works almost all the time, but in some cases the emails fails and I want to know if there is a way to retry to send an email if the first fails:

This is the error that the system shows when the email fails:

> SSL: Handshake timed out

This is my code:

```
public function insertar_exportacion()

{
    $insertstatus=$this->exportaciones_model->nuevoExportacion();
    if($insertstatus)
  {
    $data['query'] = $this->exportaciones_model->obtenerDatosInsertar($insertstatus);

    //print_r($data);
    $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
    $htmlContent = $this->load->view('emailExpo_view',$data,true);

    $this->email->initialize($config);
    $this->email->set_crlf( "\r\n" );
    $this->email->to('email@email.com');
    $this->email->from('from.email@email.com');
    $this->email->cc('cc.email@email.com');
    $this->email->bcc('bcc.email@email.com');
    $this->email->subject('Actualización de Exportación');
    $this->email->attach(FCPATH . "imagenes/cari.png", "inline");
    $this->email->message($htmlContent);
    $this->email->send();

  }

}
```

And this is the confirguration in codeigniter email.php:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

$config['protocol'] = "smtp";
$config['smtp_host'] = "smtp.host.com";
$config['smtp_port'] = "25";
$config['smtp_user'] = "username@mail.com";
$config['smtp_pass'] = "Password";
$config['charset'] = "utf-8";
$config['mailtype'] = "html";
$config['newline'] = "\r\n";
```

If you know how to resend an email in codeigniter when it fails please let me know, thank you!

Comment: What does send() return if it fails?

Comment: This error message:
>SSL: Handshake timed out

Answer (score 0):

Just put inside a try/catch

```
try {
    $obj->insertar_exportacion();
} catch(\Exception $e) {
    $obj->insertar_exportacion();
}
```

Or better, put the try/catch inside your function, and call many times you want:

```
public function insertar_exportacion()
{
    try {
        //logic
        $insertstatus=$this->exportaciones_model->nuevoExportacion();
        ...
        $this->email->send();
        ...
    } catch(\Exception $e) {
        //logic to when an error occur
    }
}

for ($i=0; $i< $numberOfTries; $i++) {
    $obj->insertar_exportacion();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs send() returns true if it was successful and false if it wasn't.

```
if (!$this->email->send()) {
  $this->email->send();
}
```

[Link to docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html#sending-email)